# Build Failed with Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/xml/util/TernarySearchTree

Tags: java

I am trying to do an ant build for my application. Build is failing with the exception below.

```
BUILD FAILED
/apps/cm/cm_builds/workspace/****/server/build.xml:615: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/xml/util/TernarySearchTree
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.TokenFactory.<init>(TokenFactory.java:36)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.ScannerState.<init>(ScannerState.java:85)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:75)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.BaseParser.baseScanner(BaseParser.java:172)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.BaseParser.createScanner(BaseParser.java:164)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.BaseParser.init(BaseParser.java:213)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.BaseParser.<init>(BaseParser.java:84)
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.prime(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:87)
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.setInput(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:148)
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(XMLStreamInputFactory.java:322)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.RuntimeBindingType.extractDefaultObject(RuntimeBindingType.java:336)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.AttributeRuntimeBindingType$QNameRuntimeProperty.<init>(AttributeRuntimeBindingType.java:353)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.AttributeRuntimeBindingType$AttributeQNameProperty.<init>(AttributeRuntimeBindingType.java:307)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.AttributeRuntimeBindingType.initialize(AttributeRuntimeBindingType.java:86)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.ByNameRuntimeBindingType.initialize(ByNameRuntimeBindingType.java:134)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.RuntimeBindingType.external_initialize(RuntimeBindingType.java:149)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.RuntimeBindingTypeTable.createRuntimeType(RuntimeBindingTypeTable.java:112)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.MarshallerImpl.marshalBindingType(MarshallerImpl.java:292)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:156)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:201)
    at weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.writeDescriptorBeanAsXML(BasicDescriptorManager.java:557)
    at weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.writeDescriptorBeanAsXML(BasicDescriptorManager.java:447)
    at weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.writeDescriptorAsXML(BasicDescriptorManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.jws.WebServiceWriter.writeBean(WebServiceWriter.java:85)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.jws.WebServiceWriter.processImpl(WebServiceWriter.java:43)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.jws.jaxrpc.JAXRPCProcessor.process(JAXRPCProcessor.java:27)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.jws.process.CompositeProcessor.process(CompositeProcessor.java:48)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.jws.build.JwsCompiler.buildWebServices(JwsCompiler.java:537)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.jws.build.JwsCompiler.compile(JwsCompiler.java:503)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwsModule.generate(JwsModule.java:442)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwsModule.build(JwsModule.java:306)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask.execute(JwscTask.java:242)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1391)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1254)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:830)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:284)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.xml.util.TernarySearchTree
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)`enter code here`
    ... 48 more
```

The `TernarySearchTree` class exists in 3 different jar's.

- I have copied these 3 jar's in Jenkins classpath also.
- Same way in build.xml file also for that particular target,but it's
  not pinking that jars.
- I tried to copy these 3 jar's in `Ant/lib` path also ,but the issue is
  not resolved.

Could you please guide me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The error says that this library is not defined for weblogic, you must provides the library name for the library module reference of the TernarySearchTree class in the **weblogic.xml** configuration file.

Example references library:

```
<library-ref>
    <library-name>WebAppLibraryFoo</library-name>
    <specification-version>2.0</specification-version>
    <implementation-version>8.1beta</implementation-version>
    <exact-match>false</exact-match>
</library-ref>
```

You can check more information about this here: [library-ref element references](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#1060332)